# Find TreeView Node by Value

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, performance, treeview

All my TreeView nodes have a unique ID for their Node Depth.

I want to set `Checked=True` on the TreeView Node which matches a certain value.

Currently I'm doing the following:

```
Dim value As Integer = 57

For Each n As TreeNode In tvForces.Nodes
   If n.Value = value Then n.Checked = True
Next
```

Is there a better way of finding the Node which I want to set as `Checked=True` rather than looping through each node?

I'm looking for something like:

```
Dim value As Integer = 57

n.FindNodesByValue(value)(0).Checked = True
```

Is there anything like this that I can use?

Comment: Keep in mind that tvForces.Nodes only gets the first level (root) nodes.  If you want all nodes, you'll need to traverse the tree.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pseudocode (`c#`) to demonstrate an idea using [LINQ Where()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803.aspx) + [List.ForEach():](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z.aspx)

```cs
nodes.Where(node => node.Value == "5")
     .ToList()
     .ForEach((node => node.Checked = true));
```

See `MSDN` following the links above for `VB.NET` syntax of both methods.

Answer (score 1):

```
                foreach (TreeNode node in TreeView1.Nodes)
                {
                    if (node.Value == "8")
                    {
                        node.Checked = true;
                    }
                    foreach (TreeNode item1 in node.ChildNodes)
                    {
                        if (item1.Value == "8")
                        {
                            item1.Checked = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: kindly do explain your code a bit so as to help the OP

Answer (score -1):

```
for (int j = 0; j < TreeView1.CheckedNodes.Count; j++)
    {    
        Response.Write(TreeView1.CheckedNodes[j].Value));
    }
```

Comment: Please add some explanation.